# why my boxcox transformation does not result a normal data?

Tags: matlab, normalization, normal-distribution

I am trying to deseasonalize a set of monthly water quality data consisting of 10 years. Since Box-Cox transformation may be required to rectify the anomalies like heteroscedasticity and non-normality of the residuals, I tried to this transformation before deseasonalization. I applied the transformation ([boxcox](http://www.mathworks.com/help/finance/boxcox.html) function in MATLAB) on each month data sets separately and I used Kolmogorov-Smirnov test (kstest function in MATLAB) to check if it follows normal distribution. but even after the transformation the p value is very small and the hypothesis of kstest is rejected!! So my question is this: Do I do it the right way (applying the transformation and kstest on each month separately? why I don't get a normal data-set after boxcox?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Boxcox transforms the data in order to reduce the nonnormality:

> boxcox transforms nonnormally distributed data to a set of data that
>   has approximately normal distribution.

However, this is unfortunately not the same as that it can take any dataset and transform it to a perfectly normal dataset.

My guess is that your data is too messy, so even after using boxcox it still cannot pass the kolmogorov-smirnov test.

Comment: Thank you, Is transferring it to normal distribution a necessary step for deseasonalizing the data?

Comment: @Fred Deseasonalizing usually just means defining seasons and applying a correction. In practice this is often done by either by adding a certain number depending on the season or applying a multiplication factor. Hence normality is absolutely not required for deseasonalizing. If you want more in depth answers, stats.stackexchange.com is probably the place to be.